# Solving coupled system of ODEs with python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

I have to numerically solve a coupled system of ODEs of the following form:
$$\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dot{c}(t) = R(t)f(t)\\
\dot{R}(t) = R(t)G(t),
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
where $c(t), f(t) \in \mathbb{R}^3, R(t), G(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$.
I usually solve ODEs with `solve_ivp` from `scipy.integrate` and matrix valued ODEs with the wrapper from the `odeintw` package. Is there a wrapper for coupled systems too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking about some general wrapper or of how to construct your own wrapper like

```
def odesystem(t,u):
    c, R = u[:3], u[3:12].reshape([3,3])
    dc = R.dot(f(t))
    dR = G(t).dot(R)
    return np.concatenate([dc, dR.flatten()])
```

You could also use `odeintw` with a $4\times 3$ array as state object, where then `c` is the first row and `R` the second to fourth row, `c,R=u[0],u[1:4]`.